issue in rendering component elements (MAP)
please, if anyone can help, I have an issue rendering components elements in my sidebar using map. It's a React.jsx project with Tailwind CSS.
this is the sidebar.jsx :
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { menus } from "../data/sidebardata"; 

function Sidebar() {
   
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="h-screen w-full flex overflow-hidden select-none">
                <nav className={`w-24 flex flex-col items-center bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 py-4 ${open ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}>
                    {menus.map((menu, index) => (
                        <li key={index} className="mt-3 p-2 hover:text-blue-600 dark-hover:text-blue-300 rounded-lg">
                            <a href={menu.link} className="flex flex-col items-center">
                                {menu.icon}
                                <span className="text-xs mt-2">{menu.name}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </nav>
                <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Toggle Sidebar</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Sidebar; 


AND this the sidebardata.js :
import GridViewOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GridViewOutlined';
export const menus = [
    {
        name: "Notifications",
        link: "#",
        icon: GridViewOutlinedIcon,
    },
    
];

i need help please

Findings:
Based on this documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/
This is how you render the Icon {menu.icon}
{menus.map((menu, index) => (
    <li key={index} className="mt-3 p-2 hover:text-blue-600 dark-hover:text-blue-300 rounded-lg">
        <a href={menu.link} className="flex flex-col items-center">
            {menu.icon}
            <span className="text-xs mt-2">{menu.name}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
))}

And this is how you store your icon
export const menus = [
    {
        name: "Notifications",
        link: "#",
        icon: GridViewOutlinedIcon,
    },
    
];

Solution 1: to return ReactElement instead for your menu icon.
export const menus = [
    {
        name: "Notifications",
        link: "#",
        icon: <GridViewOutlinedIcon />,
    },
    
];

Solution 2: to use the menu.icon and instantiate the icon instead
{menus.map((menu, index) => {
   const Icon = menu.icon;

   return (
    <li key={index} className="mt-3 p-2 hover:text-blue-600 dark-hover:text-blue-300 rounded-lg">
        <a href={menu.link} className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <Icon />
            <span className="text-xs mt-2">{menu.name}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
   )
))}


You can choose either of the solution.
